# Creating a Time Series when the data is on a monthly basis starting from April, 2004

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, data-science

I am trying to create a time series of oil barrel prices since 2004. Now as financial year in India starts from April and ends at March, I have collected the monthly average prices beginning from April, 2004 and ending at March, 2020. Please tell me if the code written hear will solve my issue?

```
oil_price_ts <- ts(barrel_prices, start = c(2004,4), end = c(2020,3), frequency = 1);
```

The issue is some sources say that

```
c(2004,4) and c(2020,3)
```

will mean 4th Quarter of 2004 and third quarter of 2020. I want to specify the starting and ending months rather. So I am confused and any clarity of this topic will be of great help.
Thanks and Regards!

Comment: A cursory look at the documentation (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/ts) suggests that it depends on your input frequency. 4 for quaters, 12 for months. `c(2004,4)` and `c(2020,3)` just return 2D vectors. It has no special meaning. You give them meaning with the additional context you pass into `ts`

Comment: So you think that I should change the frequency to 12?